# unable to install xdebug on for php 7.2 on apache 2.4 on window 7

Tags: php, apache

I tried adding xdebug to my PHP. I download `xdebug.dll` from https://xdebug.org/download.php and adding this dll to the `ext` folder in my PHP. Then open `php.ini` from PHP directory and add these lines:

```
zend_extention="C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v7.2/ext/php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2- 
vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

and reboot Apach.

And when I run phpinfo() on this server there is no information about xdebug
[image]

Comment: What do your logs say? Also you should have a clear question.

Comment: phpinfo() will also tell you where it is including php.ini from; are you storing your xdebug dll in the right place?  My php7.0 installation is in /Program Files/ rather than /Program Files (x86)/

Comment: Yes, in right place, because when I uncomment 
    zend_extension=opcache
and I see this text added:
 with Zend OPcache v7.2.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Where I can find logs? Should I switch on it in php.ini?

Comment: Ok, I added error_log path and then reboot apache and there is no errors in this file. And log_errors = on

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by renaming my downloading dll to xdebug.dll and adding zend_extension=xdebug in php.ini